# problem book for analysis as a prelude to Royden's real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I am looking for a problem book which I can use for strengthening my understanding of real analysis (i read Tao's analysis I&II and about 2/3rds of baby rudin) so that it can prepare me for studying Royden's real analysis or Folland's real analysis. I have taken a look at Charalambos Aliprantis's book on problems in real analysis but i don't think it suits my particular circumstance. Any suggestions please?

Comment: See if [**Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Real Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070602212) suits your needs. It covers Lebesgue integration, but at a much lower level than Royden or Folland.

Comment: Thanks.. i'll take a look